# Rules of using prepositions

Tags: grammar

> 1. I am going to present you some news.
> 2. I am going to present to you some news.

Are both these sentences correct? If they are both correct, then why in the first sentence is there no preposition (to) after a verb (present). I have come across many sentences in this format where to me it appears like a preposition should have been used but I do not know why it is like that.

Comment: Neither sounds idiomatic to me. I would say "I am going to present some news to you".

Comment: A better sentence pair, to support your question about prepositions, might be: *I am going to read you a story* and *I am going to read to you a story.* Do you agree?

Comment: Try a good dictionary. You should find a suggestion for adding a preposition to the first sentence that will make it an acceptable alternative to @nnnnnn improvement of your second. But this sort of question belongs on English Language Learners, not here.

Comment: 'Present' and 'news' don't collocate except on say TV programmes. 'I am going to present you an opportunity.' is barely (at best) grammatical. // 'I am going to present to you an opportunity.' is totally grammatical, but formal / literary. // 'I am going to present you with an opportunity.' is totally grammatical and idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general rule in English that **bitransitive verbs** like *give*, *send*, *offer*, *promise*, *sell*, *lend*, *show*, *tell* can have two different syntaxes.

Either

> I gave the book to John

or

> I gave John the book.

Similarly

> I am going to tell some news to you

or

> I am going to tell you some news.

However, your chosen verb, "present" does not do this so readily. I think this is because in the sense you are using it, it is not really bitransitive: though it *can* take a "to" phrase, that's not an essential part of its meaning in the way that it is for *give* and the other words. You can present a presentation even if nobody is there to see it, whereas you can't give something if there is nobody to give it to.

The same construction occurs with a **benefactive** "for" phrase, which can be added to many verbs:

> John baked a cake for me.
>
> John baked me a cake.

The verb must be transitive, and have an expressed direct object for this to be possible:

> John made breakfast for me -> John made me breakfast;

but there is no alternative form for

> John cooked for me.

Comment: +1. So would you agree that in // “John told Stephanie some great advice” // and “John told (to) Stephanie some great advice” // both have two different syntax analyses and should be analysed differently? Some of your intellect could provide some insight [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104486/discussion-on-question-by-aesking-is-to-resign-an-object-or-subject-complement).

Comment: I would regard both of those as barely acceptable, because _tell_ does not collocate with _advice_ , though I'm hard pressed to explain why. And the second is even less acceptable, because when an explicit "to" phrase is used with a bitransitive verb, it overwhelmingly follows the direct object rather than preceding it. As for syntax analysis: I guess it depends what grammatical model you favour whether or not these are different analysis.

Comment: _Present_ is, I think, borderline ditransitive. I hope this isn't another situation where we have to have a term for the usage rather than the verb per se, but I'd say that "He presented them the cheque" is acceptable to many people nowadays, whereas 'So, careers had become the only thing beyond them, other than their respective siblings who presented them with a bewildering number of nieces and nephews ...' sounds off-key without the transitivising 'with'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I think _present_ in the sense of "formally give something" is ditransitive; but in the sense of "make a public display of something" it is not. I was aware of this complexity, but didn't think it worth mentioning in context.

Comment: '...presented them [with] an opportunity ...' seems a broadening beyond either of those senses. / I never see a question here as merely part of a Q & A set-up, but also (and primarily) as an opportunity to explore the complexities of the language. In line, I believe, with site policy.

Comment: @ColinFine I found “tell X advice” is actually common. If you google “tell some advice” you will find lots of these. I even found some from: [Google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Y-8YBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%22tell+you+some+advice%22&source=bl&ots=7rD3sX-nrh&sig=ACfU3U3kDWsPd1UXYyiLdwhty0Pw5qmWlQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTjN3ZkdTnAhWSSxUIHfU3ABIQ6AEwAXoECAQQAQ) and a [radio website](http://www.arirang.com/Radio/Radio_Announce.asp?Page=1&PROG_CODE=RADR0143&MENU_CODE=101536&anno_idx=29493&code=Be4&sys_lang=Eng)

Comment: The google books link uses “Tell you some advice” and “DJ Isac will tell you some advice” from the radio website. You can find more examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tell+you+some+advice%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enGB860GB860&oq=%22tell+you+some+advice%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.5502j0j4&hl=en-GB&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8).